# two iframes side by side and responsive?

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

There is this twitch embed streaming iframe i have created, it works good side by side with the chat and perfect the way i want to, the codes are below

```css
.t_container{
    display: inline-table;
    width: 100%; 
    }
    .ts_iframe{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%; 
    }
    .tc_iframe{ 
    width: 250px;
    float:right;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="t_container">
    <div class="ts_iframe">
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="250" width="100%" scrolling="no" src="http://www.twitch.tv/esl_lol/embed"></iframe>
    </div>
  
    <div class="tc_iframe">
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="250" width="100%" scrolling="no" src="http://www.twitch.tv/esl_lol/chat"></iframe>
    </div>
  
    </div>
```

But now I have no idea how to make it to be responsive, I mean, I can make the iframes responsive but as you can see the iframes are side by side and the embed chat is smaller and it is difficult for me to apply a responsive css since I'm not quite good with it , so is it possible to be this and when visited on smaller screens like an "iPhone" the embed chat to drop under the embed video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appending this to the end of your other CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .t_container { display: block; }
    .t_container .tc_iframe { display: block; width: 100%; float:none; }
}
```

It's going to turn your table cell approach into blocks for screens that are 768 pixels wide or smaller.

Comment: That was really useful now the embed chat drops under the video ;), But, however i still need to make the embed video to be responsive because right now its still using the width and height of the iframe.

Comment: That part will be tricky because it's twitch that's generating what goes inside. There are tricks for this such as reloading the iframe with javascript when the screen resizes, but I'm not sure if Twitch supports it (other iframe integrations do like facebook and twitter feeds). However if that solved the responsive issue that you can control, please give a check! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to control the output at certain breakpoints. In this case, you can use the same concept Bootstrap would do (and does). Make them 100% width! And make sure you float them, of course.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .ts_iframe, .tc_iframe {
      float: left; 
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Herr is the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVRydN?editors=110)

Comment: The embed video still not responsive :/, Is it possible to apply this css using @media? so that would make it only available on smaller screens    
       .ts_iframe {
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom:56.25%;
 padding-top:30px;
 height:0;
 overflow:hidden;
       }

      .ts_iframe iframe {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;     '

Comment: If you want to make the video only available on smaller screen, for example lower than 768px wide, make sure you make the .ts_iframe display:none inside the media query. Same as the one I suggested

Comment: Sorry i meant to say to apply a responsive iframe css i posted in previous comment and to be applied only on smaller screens so that makes it responsive

Comment: See, the thing about iframes is that they are not 100% responsive. After all they are holding an entire document within it. If it's a video (which I couldn't see on my MacBook Pro) there are better ways to put videos in your website that is not through an iframe.

Comment: This is the best you are going to get Go to https://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/

Comment: so is there anything we can do to make the embed video to be resized smaller on phones? Thank you so much for answers